# Kubuntu 19.10: How to paste a file in Dolphin with middle click?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma, dolphin, plasma-5

How can I paste files and folders in Dolphin by middle click on empty space in Kubuntu 19.10? Dolphin's release is 19.12.1 and Plasma's version is 5.17.5 .

Comment: What do you see in System Settings →  Input Devices → Mouse module ?

Comment: You haven't said what release of Kubuntu, plasma or `dolphin` you are referring to.  The release of Kubuntu will tell us all these details.  (there is a pretty big variation in supported release covering 2016-2019)

Comment: @guiverc I'm using Kubuntu 19.10, Plasma 5.17.5, and Dolphin 19.12.1

Comment: @K7AAY just a few general settings for mouse. Middle-click paste is enabled in my system -- texts work fine, but not files and folders in Dolphin..

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question. I use Ctrl+Drag-n-Drop to copy files in Dolphin from one pane to another. It's just one step. Also, you don't need to find a totally empty space. Just don't drag-n-drop the file on another file's name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I found a possible solution to my problem.

I just used [this](https://blog.hanschen.org/2009/10/13/mouse-shortcuts-with-xbindkeys/) guide, in order to create 'Ctrl + Middle click' hotkey in my `~/.xbindkeysrc` file. Xbindkey and Xdotools are required.

In short:

1. I used `xev` and `xbindkeys -k` commands to find proper names for
       middle-click and ctrl key events;
2. Pasted the following to my `~/.xbindkeysrc` file:

   ```
       "xte 'keydown Control_L' 'key v' 'keyup Control_L'"
         Control+Mod2 + Control_L + b:2
   ```

Now, when I hold CTRL key and perform middle click on empty space in Dolphin, file is being pasted to open directory. Adding CTRL or any another second key in this shortcut is necessary, otherwise some middle mouse key functionality in KDE will be broken (e.g. closing tabs in browser).

But since my goal was to eliminate the usage of keyboard at all, I went further, and found that I can simply use my mouse's additional buttons (Back/Forward). I found a simple solution [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2154356&p=12691359#post12691359), and now I'm using [Easystroke](https://github.com/thjaeger/easystroke/wiki) utility, with "middle click + left button click" gesture configured as `Ctrl+V` command, which works just fine in Dolphin.

---

Also I wrote to Dolphin developers about the importance of implementing [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/de4sun/dolphin_are_you_interested_in_a_double_click_on/) "double/middle click on empty space" suggested feature, since they found it unnecessary and rejected. You can do the same on [bugs.kde.org](https://bugs.kde.org/buglist.cgi?bug_severity=wishlist&bug_status=UNCONFIRMED&bug_status=CONFIRMED&bug_status=ASSIGNED&bug_status=REOPENED&list_id=1708864&priority=VHI&priority=HI&product=dolphin&query_format=advanced) if you're interested in this feature, and maybe developers will change their opinion.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/97d7bz/middle_mouse_button_under_kubuntu_18_bionic/ explains you must select, not merely highlight, items to copy before you can middle-click to paste, in the Plasma 5 you noted you use in your Kubuntu.

It also suggests you may solve your issue with:

System Tray -> Right-click on the Clipboard icon (klipper) -> Configure Clipboard:
General Configuration -> Selection and Clipboard -> Synchronize contents of the clipboard and the selection

Comment: I tried to tick this option -- doesn't work. Middle-click paste for text works just fine, but doesn't work for files and folders in Dolphin.

Comment: And what "select" actually means here? What I do is: 1) click on file with right button; 2) select "copy" from pop-up menu; 3) go to another folder and middle-click on empty space -- file is not pasted.

Comment: You did it right. I'd do {Ctrl-C} instead of waiting for the pop-up, but then I'm very keyboard-centric. BTW, does the Ctrl-Drag-'n-Drop method espoused by DK Bose in their comment to the question work?

Comment: Sure, it works well. But what I want is to paste a file by middle click, without dragging and opening split screen view.

Comment: OK. That info will help Those With Minds Brighter Than Mine find the problem. You may also find help in https://forum.kde.org/viewforum.php?f=289

Comment: yeah, I've created a topic there as well. Thanks for your help